# Eclipse WST opening new XML wizard throws java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm using this code I found on the internet to open the WST wizard that helps creating a new XML file.

> ```
> public  void openWizard(String id) {
>     // First see if this is a "new wizard".
>     IWizardDescriptor descriptor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
>       .getNewWizardRegistry().findWizard(id);
>     // If not check if it is an "import wizard".
>     if  (descriptor == null) {
>       descriptor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getImportWizardRegistry()
>       .findWizard(id);
>     }
>     // Or maybe an export wizard
>     if  (descriptor == null) {
>       descriptor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getExportWizardRegistry()
>       .findWizard(id);
>     }
>     try  {
> ```

```
      // Then if we have a wizard, open it.
      if  (descriptor != null) {
        IWizard wizard = descriptor.createWizard();
        IWorkbenchWindow win = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
        WizardDialog wd = new  WizardDialog(win.getShell(), wizard);
        wd.setTitle(wizard.getWindowTitle());
        wd.open();


      }
    } catch  (CoreException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
```

I also defined the id of the wizard :

```
String XML_WIZARD_ID= "org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.wizards.NewXMLWizard";
```

and I call this function with :

```
openWizard(XML_WIZARD_ID);
```

This does't work and throws a java.lang.NullPointerException in the internal code of Eclipse.

I would like to know what can cause the problem.

Here is the stack trace :

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.WizardNewFileCreationPage.initialPopulateContainerNameField(WizardNewFileCreationPage.java:688)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.WizardNewFileCreationPage.createControl(WizardNewFileCreationPage.java:247)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.wizards.NewModelWizard$NewFilePage.createControl(NewModelWizard.java:283)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:174)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:736)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:608)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:432)  at
>   org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1104)     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:791)     at
>   org.eclipse.linuxtools.tmf.ui.views.xmlExplorer.XMLExplorerView.openWizard(XMLExplorerView.java:286)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.linuxtools.tmf.ui.views.xmlExplorer.XMLExplorerView$AddAction.run(XMLExplorerView.java:140)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:499)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$6.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:452)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1392)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3742)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3363)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

Comment: Can you show the stack trace for the exception? The one that presumably gets printed out?

Comment: Edited with the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you found on the internet is incomplete. New, Import and Export wizards implement `IWorkbenchWizard` and require that the `init` method is called before showing the wizard:

```
public void init(IWorkbench workbench, IStructuredSelection selection)
```

The `NullPointerException` is because the selection has not been set.

So after creating the wizard and before passing to `WizardDialog` you need to do something like:

```
if (wizard instanceof IWorkbenchWizard) {
   ((IWorkbenchWizard)wizard).init(workbench, selection);
}
```

where `selection` is the current selection or `StructuredSelection.EMPTY`, but not null.